# Data Value loads only on reloading, while using VueJs v-bind

Tags: vue.js, caching

Using a Vue component file, I am fetching one record from the JSON API and displaying that record data in the Template, But it works only on reloading page.  I am using axios and v-bind to fetch and display the data in the template.

I tried setting cache: false in the script section but I am not sure if that is what I need to do or how to do it.

Is there some type of cache setting I need to put or disable ?

````
  <div id="PatientList" class="container">

    <div>
      <h3 class="heading" style="text-align:left">ID {{$route.params.id}}</h3>
      <input id="lens" v-model= "search" placeholder ="Search here">
      <br><br>



  </div>


      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>



          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-bind:key="patient">
            <td>{{ patient.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.first_name + " " + patient.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.mobile }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.email }}</td>
            <td>></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>




    </div>



</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'PatientList',
  data () {
    return {

      patient: '',



    }
  },
  mounted () {


    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/Patients/'+ this.$route.params.id +'/?format=json')
      .then(response => (this.patient = response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))


  },






}






</script>

<style>
#app {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.heading {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#lens {

position: relative;
left: -468px;
}

</style>```
````

Comment: Is the problem occurring when navigating between routes that use the same component? So just the `id` is changing?

Comment: When it loads first time on a route it is working fine, when changing the route, only ID is changing and the values are not updated till a reload is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move between routes Vue will try to reuse the same components where possible. The `mounted` hook is only called the first time a component renders, so it won't be called again if the component hasn't changed.

You would need to watch for when the route param changes:

```js
watch: {
  '$route.params.id' () {
    // reload the data here
  }
}
```

A scenario that is almost identical to yours is described in the documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation. In that case it uses a `watch` on the whole of `$route` rather than specifically targeting `$route.params.id` but the end result is much the same.

Even better would be to pass the `id` as a prop to the component using the router's `props: true` setting to remove the direct dependency on `$route`, but even then you will need to watch for when the prop value changes. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle ! Works pefectly